# can't install mysql-connector

Tags: python, sql

i tried to install mysql-connector but didn't succeded

```
 pip install mysql-connector-python-rf
Collecting mysql-connector-python-rf
  Downloading mysql-connector-python-rf-2.2.2.tar.gz (11.9MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 11.9MB 33kB/s 
Installing collected packages: mysql-connector-python-rf
  Running setup.py install for mysql-connector-python-rf ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-Wnoa38/mysql-connector-python-rf/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Y29xbt-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: -c --help-commands
       or: -c cmd --help

    error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-Wnoa38/mysql-connector-python-rf/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Y29xbt-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Wnoa38/mysql-connector-python-rf/
```

can you have any idea what's the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing version 2.1.6. Works Perfectly for me.

Command:

```
pip install mysql-connector==2.1.6
```

See [this bug report on MySQL.com](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79766)

Comment: We need to install `pip` first I think. How should we do that?

Comment: comand: sudo apt-get install pip3

I think this coomand will work or you can google how to install pip.